# If you get a downvote, it is not the end of the world

Tags: discussion, down-votes

The mission of why there is voting on here (ability to up or down vote a post) is so that Good high quality posts get up-voted, and the bad low quality posts get down-voted.  The main idea of this is, the Good goes to the top, and the bad goes to the bottom.  So when someone looks at our site, they first off see Good quality posts, and hence this site can be beneficial.

This is one reason why it is very important that we have experts on here, experts/scholars/knowledgeable people can identify those answers which are not deserving of up-votes, and hence down-vote it.  Many times on here, I see obvious posts, which deserve absolutely no up-votes, get up-votes anyway.  And it would also seem, that people think that giving or getting a down-vote is bad, which is not the case.  I will mention that I am also not the only one seeing/observing this.

If you (anyone reading this post) see an answer, or question, on the [main site](https://islam.stackexchange.com/), that deserves a down-vote, give it.  Do not feel shy or ashamed of giving a down-vote, because if you don't, and you give an up-vote instead, then you are diminishing the quality of this site, and the beneficial, quality knowledge it can provide.  Now if you received a down-vote, it is not because of you, it is not because people don't like you, the problem would lie in your question or answer.  Hence before asking a question, one should meet the requirements, and the same with answering.  The major requirement for a good answer is

1. Answer with knowledge
2. Give citations/references

Now when giving a down-vote, it is recommended you also give a comment mentioning the reason you down-voted, and how the user can improve his/her question or answer.  Now one cannot go around, and if they see a post they don't agree with, just down-vote it, no here on [Islam.SE](https://islam.stackexchange.com/) we allow questions and answers from various sects that say they are Muslim.  Now one must now know the criteria which one must follow when judging whether a post needs to be down-voted or not.

**How to deem an answer worthy of down-vote:**

1. If it contains no citations/References
2. If it is spam or offensive (for this not only down-vote but flag)
3. If it does not answer the question (for this not only donw-vote but flag)
4. If it plagiarizes

**Do not down-vote if:**

1. You do not agree with it because it is not your view

The criteria for donw-voted can be discussed in further detail in future posts, I intend in this post to just clear up that it is not bad to give or get a down-vote .  I pray those who read this post benefit.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, everything is fine. Here no. of votes do decide which answer to stay on top(highlighted), so it does matter a lot.

Firstly, I feel the user who answers should be given enough time, to edit and modify his/her answer, because voting down immediately when you see it isn't good, then suggest how to improve the answer, then if the user improves his/her answer based on the suggestion and suppose this answer becomes better than any of the above highly voted answers, then this answer takes a lot more time to come on top. Because the user who down voted votes down, advices and goes away and might not come back to remove his/her down vote. Many people don't even provide comments/suggestions to improve the answer. How then will the user who's answering will learn???? So, we must try to educate even those 125+ rep guys too, how to down vote.

Comment: There are *way* more users capable of upvoting and leaving a comment than there are able to (much less *willing* to) downvote; if nobody is leaving comments to improve the post *before* it gets downvoted, or able to counter some downvotes if and when the post is actually *improved*, that's a rather fundamental problem with the community as a whole.

Comment: so there must be some protocol implemented in the community as a whole Mr Gold... @goldPseudo

Comment: @servantofWiser, the initial issue which you mentioend could be considered as a significant issue which ought to be paid attention ( that you declared"Here no. of votes do decide which answer to stay on top(highlighted), so it does matter a lot.").