# What is wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion

I got my first downvote on my first question today.

The Question was:

> [Hadith about possessing too many blankets (or bedsheets?)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37615/hadith-about-possessing-too-many-blankets-or-bedsheets)
>
> Recollecting from very long ago.
>
> I remember hearing in a Jumua some Hadith about having too many
>   possessions. It went something like "In a house there should be at
>   most three blankets (or was it bedsheets?). One for the man of the
>   house and one for the lady and one for the guest. The fourth is for
>   the devil". My recollection could be only partially correct.
>
> Can you help me identify the source of the Hadith?

I was being sincere when I asked this. This Hadith came up when I was discussing with a friend about materialism in Islam and he asked for a source but I could not find it. Today I got a downvote on the question and a comment "Ridiculously stupid question. Should be closed.".

Clearly riled me off enough to do more research and find the actual Hadith, but I wonder why the negative view(s?) of the question.

- Are source identification questions from incomplete memory discouraged here?
- Was the question framing bad?
- Or was it just that the Hadith itself looked silly?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the site!  I think the question is fine, and upvoted it.

There's some general advice here:  [If you get a downvote, it is not the end of the world](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/if-you-get-a-downvote-it-is-not-the-end-of-the-world).  But, in this particular case, I wouldn't worry about it (what else could you do?).  We cannot control how people vote, and what's a decent question to one person is worthy of a downvote to another.

The comment on your question is rude---I flagged it for moderator attention.  You can do the same.

[image]

I know it's discouraging to get a downvote---I'm hoping that the community's attitude will change over time into one where we strive for positive feedback on high-quality posts, rather then negative feedback and rude comments.  (It looks like this is going to take some patience and prayer.)

Comment: Thank you. I have a complaint that SE sites (not just IslamSE) are very newcomer-unfriendly. When someone puts up a first question that is immediately downvoted and removed, SE probably loses a user for ever.

Comment: It's a widespread problem (prompting the [3rd most upvoted question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953) on meta.SE).  People can be blunt and snarky, in an effort to save time (they're human volunteers, after all).  It doesn't matter so much if we chase off the riff-raff in an effort to [optimize for pearls](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/), but losing people who could otherwise learn the ropes and contribute is problematic.  It wouldn't hurt to be a bit nicer.

Comment: @RazimanTV The hadith you heard is about beds, not bedsheets. and it's true. In islam, the rest of unused bed (except the guest's one) are occupied by shaitan.